# Android PagerSlidingTabStrip and Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, pagerslidingtabstrip

I tried to implement PagerSlidingTabStrip

http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/pager-sliding-tabstrip/

in Fragment in place FragmentActivity, but unsuccessful. Does anyone have experience with this? Thanks.

Comment: [Usage](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip#usage)

Comment: Have you tried using the view-pager-indicator from https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator ? 

Its a very good project if you want to have a custom indicators in the bottom.

Comment: can you show us some code you have written so we have something to work with?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try my other post and see if that matches with your question :

[How to properly use fragments with ViewPager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042388/how-to-properly-use-fragments-with-viewpager/21801145#21801145)

After setting the view pager, only thing you need to do is:

```
PageIndicatorLib mIndicator = (PageIndicatorLib) findViewById(R.id.simplecircle);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(myPager);
```

Here, assume that the PagerIndicatorLib is the library project you will be using for the indicator stuff. Like I mentioned in the comment.